# When are left perpendicular categories of module categories nonempty?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $\Lambda$ be a finite dimensional hereditary algebra over algebraically closed field $k$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a full extension-closed Abelian subcategory of $mod \Lambda$ closed under direct summands and extensions that isn't $mod \Lambda$. Let $^{\bot}\mathcal{C}$ be the left perpendicular category of $\mathcal{C}$. Why is $^{\bot}\mathcal{C}$ nonzero?

Comment: Is the left perpendicular category defined by the vanishing of both $\operatorname{Hom}$ and $\operatorname{Ext}$ groups?

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon Yes, the definition is what you expected and I meant "non-zero" instead of "non-empty". Furthermore I added the condition that the Abelian category is closed under extensions and direct summands. Without the condition about extensions the hypothesis is trivially false (Take quiver $A_2$ and the Abelian subcategory generated by simples).

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon Well this is a part of the conditions.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon Oh I forgot to add that $\mathcal{C}$ is Abelian. I thought I wrote it above. Sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: This answer is currently incorrect. I will fix it once it gets corrected.

This is in fact a known result by Ingalls and Thomas (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612219) who proved the statement in Prop 2.24.